# transaction isolation level good explanation

Tags: mysql, transactions, isolation-level

Does someone knows a good book where transaction isolation levels are explained with **a lot** of examples and advices in what case what isolation level to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need a book? There's some info on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#, but I think also Oracle documentation should be very helpful: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10743/consist.htm
It's conceptually quite simple (tho technically quite complex).

Hope that helps!

Comment: No I do not really need a book :) I have read the wiki source, but the oracle source seems to be good. Thanks.